# Migration of a Yii PHP Application

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, yii

I need to change my PHP application from one server to another (Goddady to inMotionHosting)

Godaddy:
PHP: 5.3.2
MYSQL: 5.1.63

InMotion:
PHP v5.4.30
MySQL v.5.6.17

I'm Using Yii Framework v1.1.8, and I see the actual is 1.1.15.
Is it a good time to update to actual version??? Is Yii have good backwards compatibility?

I'm using JQuery 1.6.2
Should I update to JQuery 1.11.1 ??? What about v2.1.1???

I understand that updating Yii and JQuery is not necesarry, but I will soon need to update my UI. I basically want to kwow if this how trivial is the operation...

Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that jQuery 1.9 got rid of things, so for backwards compatability, there is jQuery Migrate https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Yii 1.1.8 to 1.1.15 is just bugfixes and enhancements http://static.yiiframework.com/files/CHANGELOG-1.1.15.txt. An update here shouldn't do any harm, but like always.. test first.

Upgrading to Yii v2.x is a bad idea for you right now.  The minimum PHP version is 5.4 and with that, Yii made great use of the updated language features.  However v2 is currently still in Beta and I do not recommend that for any production application exposed to potential hackers.

IMO: don't make changes to the frameworks if you don't have to and eliminate the variable when you play the "what's wrong" game.

Regardless, I hope this info helps.

Comment: Tx for your help. I see yii 2.0 is not compatible with yii 1.1 - I will update to 1.1.19. As for Php / MySQL, is it safe???